# Checking of **kwargs in concrete implementation of abstract class method. Interface issue?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, strategy-pattern, keyword-argument

I am trying to implement the Strategy design pattern to create an interface for an underlying algorithm to be implemented in a modular fashion.

Currently, as per code below, I have one top-level/parent abstract class (`ParentAbstractStrategy`) that defines the base interface for the `strategy` method.

I also have a one-level-down from this abstract class (`ChildAbstractStrategy`).

The reason I have two abstract classes is because of the attributes they need to hold; see the `__init__` methods. 
`ChildAbstractStrategy` is a special case of `ParentAbstractStrategy` in that it stores an additional attribute: `attr2`.
Otherwise its interface is identical, as seen by identical `strategy` method signatures.

Sometimes, I want to be able to directly subclass `ParentAbstractStrategy` and implement the `strategy` method (see `ConcreteStrategyA`), but other times I want to be able to subclass `ChildAbstractStrategy`, because the extra attribute is required (see `ConcreteStrategyB`).

An additional complication is that in *some* subclasses of either abstract class I want to be able to handle additional arguments in the `strategy` method. This is why I have added `**kwargs` to all signatures of the `strategy` method, so that I can pass in whatever additional arguments I want to a subclass, on a case-by-case basis.

This creates the last problem: these extra arguments are not optional in the subclasses. E.g. in the `strategy` method of `ConcreteStrategyB` I want to be certain that the caller passed in a third argument.
I'm basically abusing `**kwargs` to provide what probably should be positional arguments (since I can't give them sane defaults and need their existence to be enforced).

This current solution of using `**kwargs` for "method overloading" in subclasses feels really messy, and I'm not sure if this means there is a problem with the class inheritance scheme or interface design, or both.

Is there a way that I can achieve these design goals in a cleaner fashion. It feels like I'm missing something big picture here and maybe the class/interface design is bad. Maybe creating two disjoint abstract classes with different signatures for the `strategy` method?

```
import abc


class ParentAbstractStrategy(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, attr1):
        self.attr1 = attr1

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def strategy(self, arg1, arg2, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError


class ChildAbstractStrategy(ParentAbstractStrategy, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
        super().__init__(attr1)
        self.attr2 = attr2

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def strategy(self, arg1, arg2, **kwargs):
        raise NotImplementedError


class ConcreteStrategyA(ParentAbstractStrategy):
    def __init__(self, attr1):
        super().__init__(attr1)

    def strategy(self, arg1, arg2, **kwargs):
        print(arg1, arg2)


class ConcreteStrategyB(ChildAbstractStrategy):
    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
        super().__init__(attr1, attr2)

    def strategy(self, arg1, arg2, **kwargs):
        print(arg1, arg2)
        arg3 = kwargs.get("arg3", None)

        if arg3 is None:
            raise ValueError("Missing arg3")
        else:
            print(arg3)
```

Here's an interpreter session demonstrating how it's currently working:

```
>>> a = ConcreteStrategyA(1)
>>> a.attr1
1
>>> a.strategy("a", "b")
a b
>>> b = ConcreteStrategyB(1, 2)
>>> b.attr1
1
>>> b.attr2
2
>>> b.strategy("a", "b")
a b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/space/strategy.py", line 42, in strategy
    raise ValueError("Missing arg3")
ValueError: Missing arg3
>>> b.strategy("a", "b", arg3="c")
a b
c
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answering my own question.

My usage of `**kwargs` is 'bad' in this scenario. Why?
As far as I can tell, `**kwargs` is typically used for:

1. Wrapper functions, e.g. decorators.
2. Collecting extra keyword arguments to a function *that the function knows about* (e.g. see usage in https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html?highlight=plot#matplotlib.pyplot.plot). In this scenario the `**kwargs` are optional arguments that can be passed into the function *and* they have sane default values.

Making `**kwargs` to be *required* in a function call is defeating their purpose; positional arguments that need to be explicitly supplied should be used instead. That way the interface provided by the function *has* to be explicitly satisfied by the caller.

There is another problem with using `**kwargs` in an interface, as I have. It involves the LSP (Liskov Substitution Principle, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). The current implementation is abusing `**kwargs` in an attempt to define a variable interface for the `strategy` method among sublcasses. Although syntactically the function signatures for all `strategy` methods match, semantically the interfaces are different. This is a violation of the LSP, which would require that I could e.g. treat any descendant of `ParentAbstractStrategy` the same when considering their interfaces, e.g. I should be able to treat the `strategy` method of `ConcreteStrategyA` and `ConcreteStrategyB` the same.

What was my solution?
I have changed the interface of the `strategy` method to no longer include `**kwargs` and instead use a mix of positional arguments and keyword arguments with default values.
E.g. if `ConcreteStrategyB` still needs a third argument `arg3` but `ConcreteStrategyA` does not, I could change the classes to look like this:

```
class ConcreteStrategyA(ParentAbstractStrategy):
    def __init__(self, attr1):
        super().__init__(attr1)

    def strategy(self, arg1, arg2, arg3=None):
        print(arg1, arg2)


class ConcreteStrategyB(ChildAbstractStrategy):
    def __init__(self, attr1, attr2):
        super().__init__(attr1, attr2)

    def strategy(self, arg1, arg2, arg3=None):
        print(arg1, arg2)
        assert arg3 is not None
        print(arg3)
```

With the interfaces of both parent classes changed to match.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your findings. I'm in a similar pickle trying to implement different data filtering strategies, for most of which entry date doesn't matter while for few others it does.
I guess I'll need to drag `date=None` for my concrete strategies